# HTTP Basic Authentification via DB with Apigility

Tags: zend-framework, basic-authentication, laminas-api-tools

I've been trying to enable HTTP Basic Authentification, using the informations stores in my PSQL DB instead of the htpasswd file, but I can't seem to find a way to do so in Apigility.

As far as I've understand, I'll need to create an adapter which implements ResolverInterface and returns a "resolved" method (after the validation needed).

But I don't know how to handle it in order to be the adapter used by the HTTP Basic Authentification.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to overwrite the factory for the ZF\MvcAuth\Authentication\AuthHttpAdapter in your configuration:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'ZF\MvcAuth\Authentication\AuthHttpAdapter' => 'MyNamespace\MyHttpAdapterFactory',
    )
);
```

And in your factory you can set your resolver as the basic resolver:

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $services)
{
    $httpAdapter = parent::createService($services); // Assuming you are extending from DefaultHttpAdapterFactory
    $myResolver = $serviceManager->get('MyResolver');
    $httpAdapter->setBasicResolver($myResolver);

    return $httpAdapter;
}
```